# Community Sharing and Visibility

Tags: community, sharing, sharing-rule

I am working on a very basic community use case and need some guidance for sharing setup.

1. Share Cases with Contacts within the same Account, what's the best option to achieve the sharing?

   - Setup sharing rule for each customer account? What if there are 1000+ customer accounts?
   - Assign every contact the Manager community role, it will allow them to access each others cases.
   - **Enable "Super user permission" for each user and they will gain access to cases and contacts for their account**

FYI.. sharing set doesn't work with Community Plus licenses.

2. I want to share a custom object record with all contacts of an account?

   - What's the best way to enable this sharing model? Sharing rule or apex sharing?

Answer (score 1):

For first question to me safest option seems to be doing the sharing via apex .Through an automated trigger or a scheduler .Having increasing number of sharing rules can be issue and similarly setting multiple roles also has limits .

The other idea thats telling me is how about setting a criteria based sharing rule and sharing with groups .For every account if we have a group and add all the contacts to the group and then share the cases with right group .

If it is just one account sharing rule might be enough but if all accounts are soon candidate of this type then apex might be right choice .

Comment: I was hoping for some easy solution, but anyways thanks for confirming. As a workaround, I am designating each user as Super User, so that can see each others cases.

Comment: With community plus I have found a sharing rule can work for cases, but that was in a setup where the number of accounts was strictly limited. For scalability I think you need to use Apex sharing.